# Map clinical Document names to LOINC names

Tags: python, elasticsearch, nlp, hl7-fhir, thesaurus

I am using LOINC to match clinical document names. I am able to match Document types directly to LOINC longnames but some documents names am not able to match document type for example"operative report" in the image below.Is there any approach that we can match semantically for example "fever" and "temperature" are semantic words. Are there any other thesaurus or any clinical standrads where i can map them.
Example:

[image]